# how to get list of users who are not under belongsToMany relation under a table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

Consider the following case.
we have the `Users` table and `Tasks` table. they are in relation with `belongsToMany` with table `task_user`.

How to get the list of all users who are not under any task? i.e. their user_id is not at all under that given task or even in the `task_user` table.

why I need this is because like this we can only provide a list of users who are yet to be assigned a task. the task will be assigned to users and not a single user at a time.

Editing_____________

also how to filter with users based on group table? below is not working

```php
$users = Group::with(['subscribers' => function ($q){
            $q->doesntHave("tasks");
        }])->whereId($gid)->latest()->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've named your relationships properly, you should be able to use `doesntHave("tasks")`:

```
$tasklessUsers = User::doesntHave("tasks")->get();
```

`doesntHave()` checks for the non-existence of the supplied relationship (`"tasks"`, in this case) and returns all objects that pass this check.

If your function name is different, use that, but the relationship should be:

`User.php`:

```
public function tasks(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, "task_user");
}
```

Edit: `doesntHave()` is the simple version, `whereDoesntHave()` allows a custom query. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence for full details.

Second Edit:

As stated in the comments below, `with()` will not filter the `Model` it is being called on, so this query won't work as you'd expect:

```
$users = Group::with(['subscribers' => function ($q){
  $q->doesntHave("tasks");
}])->whereId($gid)->latest()->get();
```

To fix this, use a chained `doesntHave()` query:

```
$query = Group::doesntHave('subscribers.tasks')
->where('id', '=', $gid)
->latest()
->first();

// OR

$query = Group::whereHas('subscribers', function($subQuery){
  $subQuery->doesntHave('tasks');
})->where('id', '=', $gid)
->latest()
->first();

$users = $query->subscribers; // Return `users` (aliased to `subscribers`)
```

Either approach will check the existence of `subscribers` that don't have any associated `tasks` relationship, and also only return where `id` is `$gid`.

Note: Used `first()` for the queries, as using `id` in a query should only ever return a single `Group` record, and `get()` is for returning multiple records in a `Collection`

Comment: can you give me a example on how to do it for below code ? `$users = Group::with(['subscribers' => function ($q){
            $q->doesntHave("tasks");
        }])->whereId($gid)->latest()->get();`

Comment: your answer is very close to what i need. now how to filter that users with group id condition ? your answer will give me all the users from all the group. which i don't want

Comment: You could do it that way, or `Group::doesntHave('subscribers.task') ...`, as long as there is a relationship between `Subscriber` and `Take` models.

Comment: In the future, don't edit your question to add additional requirements. Keep questions to a single, concise problem and ask a new question if you have a separate problem. My answer answers your first question, but is much less valid as soon as you edited it...

Comment: oh sorry about that :( I just found that it will give all the users and I need to filter it based on the group. did tried the above code but failed at that. then thought to ask you on the same so added it here itself.

Comment: No worries! Just something to be aware of. The only catch is that you can't use `with()` to filter the parent Model `Group`. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: as per your updated answer. in do get the list of all the users which are don't have any task as of yet. but when I have someone from that group under a task, the above answer returns a blank. nothing at all. code `$query = Group::doesntHave('subscribedUsers.task')->whereId($gid)->first();
        return $query->subscribedUsers;` error is `Trying to get property 'subscribedUsers' of non-object`

Comment: created a new thread as I think the scope of the question is getting limited. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284155/how-to-do-the-following-with-doesnt-have-or-other-optimzed-way-in-laravel