# How to do the following with doesn't have or other optimized way in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, multiple-conditions

I have a thread which gave the answer but later on I found that I was getting limitations: [how to get list of users who are not under belongsToMany relation under a table in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273470/how-to-get-list-of-users-who-are-not-under-belongstomany-relation-under-a-table/59273525?noredirect=1#comment104755997_59273525)

so creating a new thread where I do have an answer but now how can I optimize the same with any prebuild functions like `doesntHave` or something entirely else.

below is the code which gives me the list of users who are under a group and not assigned any task. one group can have multiple tasks so only users where the task is not assigned needs to be listed.

```php
$gid = $task->group_id;
$MembersList =  $task->members;
$group_subscribers = Group::with(['subscribedUsers' => function($q){
    $q->select('id');
}])->whereId($gid)->get();
$group_subscribers = $group_subscribers[0]->subscribedUsers->pluck('id')->toArray();
$alreadyMembers =  DB::table('task_user')->select('user_id as id')->whereIn('user_id', $group_subscribers)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$finalList =  array_diff($group_subscribers, $alreadyMembers);
$users = User::whereIn('id', $finalList)->get();
return $users;
```

any way to improve the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I guessed Users and Tasks was in a many to many relationship. For my optimisation to work, i added the following relationship to the User model, this is gonna be used when we filter the subscribed users.

```
public class Users {
    public function tasks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class);
    }
}
```

Basically the implementation is filtering all the subscriber users and checking if they have tasks, since tasks is a relationship it returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) and `isNotEmpty()` is used for that reason.

```
$groupId = $task->group_id;

$group = Group::with(['subscribedUsers.tasks'])->find($groupId));

$withoutTasks = $group->subscribedUsers->filter(function ($user) {
    return $user->tasks->isNotEmpty();
} );

return $withoutTasks;
```

It is a rule of thumb to avoid DB:: methods and you should be able to go to model to model, instead of making queries from getting from one model to another.

Comment: will check this today and update here on the same :)

Comment: Did it help your problem?

Comment: please wait for a bit as at the time i got the answer from your side, i had to move to other part where i am facing issue. so let me solve that first as old code is working, then will implement your answer and update it here.